# Set the i-th bit to zero?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I would like to set the i-th bit to zero no matter what the i-th bit is.

```
  unsigned char pt = 0b01100001;
  pt[0] = 0; // its not how we do this...
```

Setting it to one, we can use a mask `pt | (1 << i)` but i'm not sure how to create a mask for setting 0, if thats possible.

Comment: Try with bitwise-AND.

Comment: @JasonBaker Nope, that post is not showing how to set a bit to nothing but zero.

Comment: @GivenPie the accepted answer has a section for each task (set, clear, toggle, check...)

Comment: @JasonBaker Right, clearly I didn't understand what clearing a bit even meant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just have to replace the logical `OR` with a logical `AND` operation.  You would use the `&` operator for that:

```
pt = pt & ~(1 << i);
```

You have to **invert** your mask because logical `AND`ing with a `1` will maintain the bit while `0` will clear it... so you'd need to specify a `0` in the location that you want to clear.  Specifically, doing `1 << i` will give you a mask that is `000...010..000` where the `1` is in the bit position that you want, and inverting this will give `111...101...111`.  Logical `AND`ing with this will clear the bit that you want.

Comment: thanks, made alot of sense

Comment: @GivenPie - No worries!... but that duplicate question that is being pointed to is much more comprehensive.  Suggest you give that a read too.

Answer (score 3):

You could stick with this:

```
// Set bit at position `bitpos` in `pt` to `bitval`
unsigned char bitpos = 1;
unsigned char pt = 0b01100001;
bool bitval = 1;

// Clear the bit
pt &= ~(1u << bitpos);
// Set the bit
pt |= (bitval << bitpos);
```