# How to set bit and print all bits in number using C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I have following function to print bits:

```
void printBits(unsigned int num)
{
   for(int bit=0;bit<(sizeof(unsigned int) * 8); bit++)
   {
      printf("%i ", num & 0x01);
      num = num >> 1;
   }
}
```

and I want to set bit number 5 as follow:

```
unsigned int DataInMemory = 0x00000000;
DataInMemory |= (1<<5);
```

the result of printBites function is:

> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

it means that `1 << 5` set bit 6 not bit 5. Is it difference between bit position (indexes) and bit in programming nomenclature?
How to set bit and print all bits in number using C?

Comment: It did set bit no. 5 (i.e.: the 6th bit). Bit indices start counting at 0, not 1.

Comment: Anybody who thinks this can be kept open let me know. Will open it.

Comment: @ElConrado.: Those duplicates help you? Is it ok?

Comment: @水飲み鳥 comment is useful. It's ok.

Comment: @coderredoc OP's problem is actually (implicitly) explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004263/set-the-i-th-bit-to-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1), not in the answers, but actually in the question itself. Could you please consider to add that post to the list?

Comment: @水飲み鳥.: Added..